# What does this "it" indicate?

Tags: cleft-constructions

> It is a pleasure to me to reflect upon this subject in the language of Burke, who uttered the well-known touching eulogy over the neglected bier of its European prototype.
>
> **It** argues a sad defect of information concerning the Far East, when so erudite a scholar as Dr. George Miller did not hesitate to affirm that, chivalry, or any other similar institution, has never existed either among the nations of antiquity or among the modern Orientals.[Source](http://www.sacred-texts.com/shi/bsd/bsd06.htm)

I don't understand this sentence.
I think it should be, "It argues a sad defect of information concerning the Far East that so erudite a scholar as...did not hesitate...."

Is the writer's sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: Mr, StoneyB I would like you to address this thread, too. You seem to be pretty knowledgeable about this. http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19612/meaning-of-as-to-be?noredirect=1#comment36424_19612

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in detecting an error in this sentence. But the error does not lie in the conjunction, *when* rather than *that*, but in the tense of the verb *hesitate*.

This sentence is long, so let’s start by simplifying it, to make the pieces stand out:

- I reduce *It argues a sad defect of information concerning the Far East* to **It shows ignorance**.
- I reduce *when so erudite a scholar as Dr. George Miller did not hesitate to affirm that, chivalry, or any other similar institution, has never existed either among the nations of antiquity or among the modern Orientals* to **when he said that**

You believe that sentence 1, below, is ungrammatical, and should be rewritten as sentence 2:

1. <sup>?</sup> It shows ignorance when he said that.
2. <sup>ok</sup>It shows ignorance that he said that.

Your rewrite, 2, is an [*It-*cleft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleft_sentence)<sup>†</sup>: a ‘canonical’ sentence in which a subordinate clause acts as the subject is ‘transformed’ by moving the subordinate clause to the end of the sentence and replacing it as subject with the dummy pronoun *it*:

```
 2a. [That he said that] shows ignorance.
       V      ^—————————————————————————————v  
 2.   It                shows ignorance [that he said that].
```

Your objection to sentence 1 appears to be that a *when* clause is an adverbial and should not be employed as an NP argument. This objection is echoed by the old school of ‘prescriptive’ grammarians; generations of schoolteachers have tried to stamp out such uses as:

> A gaffe is when a politician accidentally tells the truth.
>   A circle is when all the points on a curve are the same distance from a single point.

This construction is in consequence avoided in formal English. It is only formally acceptable to use a *when* clause as an NP in the predicate, where it is taken to be a ‘pro-form’ (like a pronoun) referring to a particular named **time**:

> Now is when we should act.
>   Monday is when I expect to be finished.

And that in effect is how it is used here: it identifies the *event* or *occasion* which argues a sad ignorance of the East.

But this does **not** mean that *when* is equivalent to *that* as a complementizer. You cannot simply replace *that* with *when*. *When* clauses have two constraints which *that* clauses do not:

- *When* clauses in subject position at the head of a sentence must be followed by a dummy *it*.

  > <sup>∗</sup> When he said that showed ignorance.
  >   <sup>ok</sup>When he said that **it** showed ignorance.
- *When* clauses must agree in tense with the matrix verb. This is the error in sentence 1:

  > 1.  <sup>∗</sup> It **shows** ignorance when he **said** that.
  >   1a. <sup>ok</sup>It **showed** ignorance when he **said** that *OR*
  >   1b. <sup>ok</sup>It **shows** ignorance when he **says** that.

To my mind, both of these constraints are  ‘surface’ adjustments made because *when* clauses are ordinarily temporal. That makes a difference in tenses sound odd. It also means that a *when* clause at the beginning of a sentence will at first be understood as an adverbial. Consequently, the *it* is required to clarify its role. Note that this *it* can also be employed with *that* clauses:

> That he said that, it shows ignorance.

---

<sup>†</sup>:  Some grammarians distinguish what we are talking about here from *cleft* sentences and treat this as a species of [*extraposition*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition). On this analysis, only *It* constructions with *be* + relative clauses qualify as clefts:

> It was ignorance that was shown when he said that.

I think this is a false distinction. Distinguishing clefts from extrapositions is often very difficult, so I prefer to regard the different sorts of *It* construction as a single species. But the analysis of clefts is very controversial.

Comment: @user4550 Here you go. I'm killing my previous comments, so we can start afresh!

Comment: You are saying this "it" in the original sentence is the same as "I like it when you do that."? So this dummy it plus when construction is possible when the dummy it is the subject of the sentence? Like "It is great when you do that!"

Comment: And also, "When grace is joined with wrinkles, it is adorable. There is an unspeakable dawn in happy old age." This "it" is also dummy without any specific subject?

Comment: @user4550 The exact role of *it* in these sentences is controversial; some grammarians think of it as a pronoun referring to what comes before or after, some say it is just a placeholder. Follow the links I have provided on *cleft* and *extraposition* and you'll see very brief discussions of the problem; the literature is too extensive to go into here, and anyway doesn't come to a firm conclusion.

Comment: But it doesn't deal with "it...when" clause where the "it" is a dummy pronoun. How would you interpret the "It" in these sentences? Can I say "it is funny when you do it." with the meaning that this "it" is a dummy pronoun?

Comment: @user4550 Certainly you can say that. But whether *it*  is 1) a dummy, a placeholder, or 2) refers to a specific entity (*when you do it*) is just the question grammarians don't agree on. We know **what** the sentence means, but we don't agree about **how** it means it. And unless you are going to be a professional linguist I wouldn't worry about the **how**, just the **what**. (If you **are** going to be a professional linguist, you need to spend a couple months reading the professional literature!)

Comment: I see. But what you are saying in your answer is that you lean toward the "dummy it" proposition in these sentences?

Comment: @user4550 I do. But I would not want you to think that everybody agrees with me!

Comment: That's why in another forum everyone told me that the "it" in the "When grace is joined with wrinkles, it is adorable. There is an unspeakable dawn in happy old age." meant "face" so I was like "oh this "dummy "it" plus "when" cleft construction is not grammatical." This shows the divide you are talking about?

Comment: @user4550 No, I think your respondents were simply wrong! Certainly these clefts/extrapositions are grammatical; the question is how they are grammatical, which is very hard to answer.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your clarification. I would appreciate your answer on this. http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19612/meaning-of-as-to-be?noredirect=1#comment36424_19612